# How to know when new video is uploaded to a youtube channel with Python

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, youtube-api

How to know when new video is uploaded to the special YT channel? I tried do some with youtube v3 data api, but didn't understand anything.

How can I get information about a new video? Or how to use youtube v3 data api?

Comment: That would&should be researchable in the yt api documentation. asking here itis far too broad a problem and offtopic. Do you have code as [mre] we can help you with?

Comment: thanks, thats true. I need to remove this topic